# whats the maximum length of svg d (data) attribute string the morden browsers accept?

Tags: html, svg

The svg path specification says

> 'The processing of the BNF must consume as much of a given BNF
>   production as possible, stopping at the point when a character is
>   encountered which no longer satisfies the production.'

In practice whats the limit (in Safari/Chrome/FF/IE etc)? Whats the maximum length a single path element take for its d (data) attribute?

Comment: There is no limit. Performance does generally decrease as the length increases though.

Comment: in that case, will breaking a single path into multiple path elements help (question 2 ;) )?

Comment: Possibly, depends on the UA, the version, the O/S. I.e. try it and see.